# Убирание скролла при открытии модального окна bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Подскажите, как убрать у боди скрол при открытии модального окна bootstrap

Comment: какая версия bootsstrap ?

Comment: 3.6 версия.........

Answer (score 3):

css:

```
body.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

js:

```
$("#myModal").on("show", function () {
   $("body").addClass("modal-open");
}).on("hidden", function () {
   $("body").removeClass("modal-open")
});
```

Comment: не работает ((( бутстрап переопределяет

Comment: замени на  overflow:hidden !important;